# Parsing unicode 'Vulgar Fractions' into double in Java

Tags: java, regex, unicode, double

I am scraping some data of a web site and parts of it include fractions in unicode e.g. 6' 5¼". I have successfully used the regex `(\\d)' (\\d{1,2}([\\xbc-\\xbe])?)\"` to extract each part of the String.

This gives me two strings, one is `"6"` and the other is `"5¼"`.

The troublesome part is the bit that contains the unicode vulgar fractions. Obviously it does not parse correctly using `Double.parseDouble`.

I have looked everywhere for examples for Java but have been unable to find any, how would I go about getting ¼ out as 0.25?

If it makes it easier I can split the regex up again so it returns the fraction part seperately so I get three strings out instead of two.

Comment: map the vulgar versions to their realworld values, probably.

Comment: I had seen that solution, but would rather not have the values hard coded in, but if that is what it comes down to then I may not have any other choice.

Comment: What about first replacing like `s = s.replace("¼", ".25").replace("½", ".5")-replace("¾", ".75");`?

Comment: pretty much. `¼` may mean something to us humans, but to a computer it's a character like most others, no different than `a` or `P`

Comment: `would rather not have the values hard coded in` How many are there to hard code? If they are sequential in character code you may be able to first, do a bounds check of the character, then do a little math like code of matched char minus code of base character times a conversion, then convert to a string.

Answer (score 10):

There is a way to do it without having your own table of vulgar fractions to values, you can use the one built into the Unicode data.

If you convert to Unicode Normalization Form KD, it'll decompose fractions into a fraction-slash (U+2044) surrounded by plain numbers. So you could do something like:

```
String[] fraction = Normalizer.normalize("¼", Normalizer.Form.NFKD).split("\u2044");
if (fraction.length == 2) {
    double value = (double) Integer.parseInt(fraction[0]) / Integer.parseInt(fraction[1]);
}
```

There are more fraction characters than the ones in the range U+00BC–U+00BE, for example ⅛, so if you want to avoid hard-coding that range I'd suggest changing the regexp for it to something like `[^\d]?`.

Comment: Wish I could give this answer more than just a +1.  I _need_ java.text.Normalizer in an application that I am working on right now, and I did not know it!

Answer (score 2):

> [I...] would rather not have the values hard coded in

Do you expect the meaning of ¼ to change?  I would "hard code" the values using an enum:

```
enum VulgarFraction {
    ...,
    ONE_QUARTER('¼', 0.25),
    ONE_HALF('½', 0.5),
    ...
    ;

    private final char codepoint;
    private final double value;

    VulgarFraction(char codepoint, double value) {
         this.codepoint = codepoint;
         this.value = value;
    }

    char getCodepoint() { return codepoint; }

    double getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a function I wrote for anyone looking to do this in Kotlin

```
fun fromVulgarFraction(number:String):Double {
val items = number.split("""\d""".toRegex()).filterNot { it.isEmpty() }
val mixed: String?
val fraction = mutableListOf<String>()
return if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
    mixed = items.first()
    fraction.addAll(Normalizer.normalize(mixed, Normalizer.Form.NFKC).split("\u2044"))
    val decimal = fraction[0].toInt().toDouble() / fraction[1].toDouble()
    val result = """\d+""".toRegex().find(number)
   if (result != null) {
        result.value.toDouble() + decimal
    } else {
        decimal
    }
} else {
    number.toDouble()
}
```

}

examples:

2¼ -> 2.25

Comment: sample https://pl.kotl.in/IlSSmtp1w?theme=darcula